# neo4j with jetty webserver for config trouble

Tags: neo4j, jetty

I am using sparql-plugin and rest with neo4j 
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/sparql-plugin

the query of return rows will be really big , like 2 millions triple above.
but the response content length is always small.

Is there a way to config the jetty "ResponseBufferSize" that Neo4j is using.

What I know now is neo4j use jetty with multiple jar

jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar

jetty-http-9.0.5.v20130815.jar

jetty-io-9.0.5.v20130815.jar

jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar

jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar

jetty-webapp-9.0.5.v20130815.jar

jetty-xml-9.0.5.v20130815.jar

How can I config this or using jetty.xml?

Comment: Why is the response content-length small? You should be able to stream the result by using a header X-Stream:true

Comment: Jetty is set-up programmatically within Neo4j, there are no jetty options exposed. It should be opaque to a user.

Comment: There is no relationship between Jetty's `ResponseBufferSize` and small `Content-Length` being seen on the response itself.